# How to wire new Honeywell smart wifi thermostate( RTH9590WF) to replace older Honeywell thermostat using only 3 wires

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

Old thermostat was only using 3 wires, connected to W, G and R-Rc jumper. no C wire.  Does have extra wires not being used at each end. Big question is what to I connect to at the furnace for a power source for the new wifi thermostat? There is only Y, and Com 24V Terminals available on the furnace board.  Can I use Com 24v at furnace terminal and C wire at thermostat?

Comment: Can you post a photo of each end?

Comment: What's the make and model of the furnace?

Comment: Do you have a volt/multimeter? If so, what's the voltage between the `R` and `COM 24V` terminals?  Is there currently anything attached to the `COM 24V` terminal?